# Keep getting error when using eventhandler, syntax error

Tags: vb.net, function, events, event-handling, addhandler

I am trying to  control when a event is firing and having some issus.
This is what I tried ,following the documentation on [MSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement)

Can anybody see the error here?

*BC30677 Visual Basic or statement event operand must be a dot-qualified expression or a simple name.*

```
Public Class Formx

Public Sub test()

        Dim Objectfx As New Formx()

        RemoveHandler Objectfx.Button2_Click(), AddressOf Button2_Click

    End Sub

end Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the association of a delegate to its event handler with this syntax.

```
 RemoveHandler Objectfx.Click, AddressOf Button2_Click
```

It seems that Objectfx is a button not a Form but in any case the first parameter of RemoveHandler is the delegate that has been assigned with a compatible event handler passed as second argument